# Localstorage vs cloudstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am a newbie and trying to conceptualize my first mobile app using HTML5 & JavaScript. I am struggling to think where I would store my data for a production native app. So for e.g. if I have a To-do app, where should I be storing the list of todo items, on the HTML5 local-storage option or use a cloud-DB?

Answer (score 0):

If the TODO data is to be shared between devices used by the same user, it would ideally be stored on the cloud with syncing happening *to/from* the device localStorage. If not, going beyond local storage may not be needed at all.

Comment: ... and IMHO local storage is a must. I wouldn't want a TODO app that doesn't work when I'm not on-line.

Comment: thanks, but a follow up questions. Can the user not remove the localstorage data accidentally when he clears his browser cache? And for a web app on mobile, will the localstorage data persist between phone restarts? thanks..